# excel created a password to unprotect a sheet without me telling it to

Tags: vba, passwords

I have a protected sheet with certain cells unlocked for editing. I have button click macros that run various processes that temporarily unprotect the sheet to allow the code to run, then protect it again when done. example:

```
sub macro1()

activesheet.unprotect

' code here

activesheet.protect allowsorting = true

activesheet.protect allowfilter:= true

end sub
```

for some reason when I run these macros now, it is asking for a password that I never put in there. the sheet should not be password protected. I ran a password breaker macro and it told me the password is "AAAAAAAABABF"

what would cause this, and how to I remove it from asking for a password? 
can't seem to find any results in the forum with this issue.
thanks for your help

Comment: Password breaker should return one usable password is "sometext". I can't remember whether that is what you then use or if the sheet is actually now not protected. Did you try both the suggested password and also entering blank as password? In the above example, you aren't specifying a password so have you tried a blank password entry and then press enter?

Comment: so I plugged in the password it told me to. and the macro then runs as intended, but my problem is I don't want any passwords on this sheet. I've never password protected it, I just want to keep users of this file from accidently deleting data, while also allowing sorting and use of auto-filters. I ran the password breaker just so I could keep from getting locked out of my own sheet.

Comment: do I need a password when I protect the sheet, and then in the code to unprotect it, tell excel to use that password automatically? sorry I am mostly unfamiliar with how protecting/unprotecting sheets work for the most part

Comment: You need to specify the password you set otherwise just saying unprotect without the password is saying password = “”. So specify the password next to unprotect and again next to protect. Unless you intend to not specify password. See @vityata answer also regarding error leaving protect on.

Comment: And don’t run password breaker unless you are locked out

Comment: thanks for the quick response. this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the code, thus the password protection gets activated on this line `activesheet.protect allowsorting = true`. To avoid errors like this one, make sure that you always use `Option Explicit` on the top.

In general, this should be ok:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    'code
    ActiveSheet.Protect AllowSorting:=True
    ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Concerning the `AAAAAAAABABF`, it is not the password you have set, but its  hashed value is the same as the hashed value of your password.

If you want to see yourself, try just this code:

```
Sub TestMe
     ActiveSheet.Unprotect AllowSorting = True
End Sub
```

It is a bit meaningless, but as far as you have used `"AllowSorting = True"` as a password, you can use it for the unprotect.

Comment: @dusty_j - and it is quite fun to see how `ActiveSheet.Unprotect AllowSorting = True` actually manages to unlock the worksheet.

Comment: @dusty_j - write `Option Explicit` on top, then the syntax check is automatic.